# mnlogit with float dependent variable

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want to estimate some multinomial equation of the form:

```
'L2 ~ C(v)'
```

and run

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
res = smf.mnlogit('L2 ~ C(v)', data=test[test.v == 0.2]).fit()
```

I get

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 1.036628
         Iterations 5
```

But when I want to print the results, I see

```
print(res.summary())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2847, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-45-5240cd5460e8>", line 1, in <module>
    asd.summary()
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py", line 2559, in summary
    yname, yname_list = self._get_endog_name(yname, yname_list)
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py", line 2945, in _get_endog_name
    ynames = ['='.join([yname, name]) for name in ynames]
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py", line 2945, in <listcomp>
    ynames = ['='.join([yname, name]) for name in ynames]
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, numpy.float64 found
```

My testing data (a `pandas` dataframe) has a single `x` and two `y` values, so I expect the fixed-effect regression to give me a probability of `4/19` of `y==0.152577` and `15/19` of `y==0.341053`:

```
      v        L2
30  0.2  0.152577
31  0.2  0.152577
32  0.2  0.152577
33  0.2  0.152577
34  0.2  0.341053
35  0.2  0.341053
36  0.2  0.341053
37  0.2  0.341053
38  0.2  0.341053
40  0.2  0.341053
41  0.2  0.341053
42  0.2  0.341053
43  0.2  0.341053
44  0.2  0.341053
45  0.2  0.341053
46  0.2  0.341053
48  0.2  0.341053
49  0.2  0.341053
```

Why am I seeing the error? I am on statsmodels `0.8`

Comment: That's looking something like a bug. What do you get from `res.summary()` i.e. without `print`?

Comment: @roganjosh I get the same

Comment: I'd raise on their github tbh.The amount of times I get that error using `join`...

Comment: Yes it looks like a bug in constructing the ynames. There might be a workaround by setting the ynames directly. However, using float endog might not be robust in terms of identifying the classes correctly.